# how to take sum of column of datatype str and group by another column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate sum of column_name "Email" and trying to groupby column_name "country". The error is in converting str to int

Script:

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('hi.csv',sep = ',')
df3['h1'] = df3['h1'].astype(int)
new_df3=df3.groupby(['country']).h1.sum().to_frame('count').reset_index()
print(new_df3)
```

Input:

```
cou h1
A   hi
C   watsup
G   hi
```

Comment: Chek second answer.

Comment: Please share the original one if this is duplicate

Comment: OK, can you explian why is not duplicate? I have no problem reopen question, if not dupe.

Comment: `df3 = pd.read_csv('1912.csv',sep = ',')
new_df3=df3.groupby(['country']).size().reset_index(name='current_email_count')`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df3.groupby('country')['Email1'].count()
```

there is no need to convert email to `int` just counting emails should do the work.

Comment: getting error : can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: